# Working with substrings

Tags: c

I have string `char * buff` and want to work on its susbtring (from `buff + x` till  `buff + y`.
Do I have to copy this sting to other variable? Or is there any better way to reach it?
Right now I only want to write this substring to a file.

Comment: It depends on what "work" means and where it will be used afterthat. No need to copy if you just read it.

Comment: I want to write this substring to a file.

Comment: If writing with `fwrite` is good enough, then it's doable. Otherwise, you may want to copy (or temporarily set `buff[y]` to NUL).

Comment: I see. Sorry I meant that you didn't change the string by writing a file

Answer (score 3):

No, just do the write directly just as you wish:

```
fwrite(buff + x, y - x + 1, 1, my_file);
```

The above assumes a closed interval by the way, if you mean a half-open you need to remove the `+ 1`. For instance, with `const char *buff = "hello, world";` the above will write `"world"` if `x = 7` and `y = 12`.

The write will be done from the "slice" of your buffer, since that's all you say to `fwrite()`. It has no idea that the data it receives is part of something larger, of course.

As pointer out in a comment, the above treats the slice as binary data which might be bad if it's really a string. In that case, to be able to use e.g. `fprintf()` with `%s`, you should use a dynamic format string (you need `%.Ns` where N is `y - x + 1`):

```
static int substring_print(const char *s, size_t start, size_t end)
{
  char fmt[16];

  snprintf(fmt, sizeof fmt, "%%.%us", end - start + 1);
  fprintf(stdout, fmt, s + start);
}
```

Comment: Of course, this assumes binary output is good enough (no newline interpretation needed).